# Join depending on generic type

Tags: java, jpa, generics, criteria

My RefineByBasicTaskType should add the same criteria for different CriteriaQuery types. T could be a Task or a Appointment. The only difference is, that there is no join needed if T is a Task.

How can I use my RefineByBasicTaskType class for multiple types?

```
public class RefineByBasicTaskType<T> extends AbstractRefinement<T> {

private BasicTaskType basicTaskType;

public Predicate addCriteriaQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteria, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<T> taskRoot) {
    
    if (T instanceof Task) {
        return refineByBasicTaskType(builder,
                                     taskRoot);
    }

    return refineByBasicTaskType(builder,
                                 fetchOrCreateFirstJoin(taskRoot,"task"));
}...
```

Comment: You might have a design problem. You can't do what you're trying to do without adding a `Class<T> clazz` parameter to the method and doing `if(clazz.equals(Task.class))`, or preserving the type in some other way. The `T` is erased so you can't use it for `instanceof` or other operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a proper object oriented point of view you are trying to re-invent mechanisms that are already possible with inheritance:

```
public abstract class RefineByBasicTaskType<T> extends AbstractRefinement<T> {

  public abstract Predicate addCriteriaQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteria, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<T> root);
}
```

```
public class RefineByTask extends RefineByBasicTaskType<Task> {
  
  @Override
  public Predicate addCriteriaQuery(CriteriaQuery<Task> criteria, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<Task> root) {
    return refineByBasicTaskType(builder, root);
  }
}
```

```
public class RefineByWhatever extends RefineByBasicTaskType<Whatever> {
  
  @Override
  public Predicate addCriteriaQuery(CriteriaQuery<Whatever> criteria, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<Whatever> root) {
    return refineByBasicTaskType(builder, fetchOrCreateFirstJoin(root, "task"));
  }
}
```

Edit: If you don't want to use inheritance you should be able to get the Java type from the `Root` object so you could also replace your `if`-statement with:

```
if (taskRoot.getJavaType().equals(Task.class)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Smutje, both of your solutions work fine. I used the inheritance which is unfortunately more code, but clearer